# Haproxy bypass if Down

Tags: linux, http, dns, haproxy

How to bypass Haproxy load balancer if the main node is Down without changing DNS?

Let's say that I have server A (Haproxy) which balances on server b and c, but what if the main server A goes down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically setup a fail over to another HAProxy server. If you are doing active/passive that is usually handled by keepalived - it would automatically move the IP to the passive HAProxy server.